# Recreating an existing Cognito User Pool in AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have a user pool in my Amplify project that has a single custom field configured incorrectly. Because you can't edit or delete the fields, my plan is to recreate the user pool. The app isn't in production yet so having some downtime is ok.

My question is, what is the cleanest way to recreate a user pool within the Amplify CLI?  I need it to be identical in every way except for that single custom field.  When I attempt to remove the auth category it throws an error because of the admin query API and my lambda functions.

Ideally I wouldn't have to run through the steps of creating it, my current configuration would be used.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Going through this now. Did you resolve your issue? If no updates from your part, I'll update with an answer once I sort it out.

Comment: No I never did figure it out and am still in need of a solution. I just created a second custom field to work around it which isn’t ideal.

Comment: Cognito User Pools cannot be modified. AWS Amplify does not support custom fields yet.

Hence, the solution I came to was to run `amplify delete` and re-run the amplify commands to re-add auth/api/function since I was at my very first week of troubleshooting this.

An alternative I have considered, when I have time, is to figure out how to customize the cloud formation templates generated by Amplify to add the custom field- as I'm adding it manually using the AWS console- which is not ideal.